Is MSVC correct in rejecting this code with /permissive-?
Here is the complete example on godbolt.org, and the code is copied below:
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <optional>

namespace foo {
    template <std::size_t>
    using size_t = int;
}

using namespace foo;

struct Foo {
    Foo() : a{} {}
    std::array<std::optional<int32_t>, 2> a;
};

int main() {}

MSVC, when compiling with the flag /permissive-, rejects the code with this message:
predefined C++ types (compiler internal)(421): error C2872: 'size_t': ambiguous symbol
<source>: note: could be 'unsigned __int64 size_t'
<source>(7): note: or       'foo::size_t = int'
predefined C++ types (compiler internal)(421): note: the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
<source>(13): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void __builtin_array_init_helper<_Ty>(_T *,size_t) noexcept' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=std::optional<int32_t>,
            _T=std::optional<int32_t>
        ]
Compiler returned: 2

On the other hand, both MSVC without that flag and Clang and GCC with or without the flag -fno-permissive, accept the code.
Besides, given the MSVC with /permissive- case, each one of the following changes individually makes the code compile:

removing the std::array layer from a,
removing the std::optional layer from a,
removing the manually defined default ctor,
removing just the initializer list from the default ctor,
removing the using namespace foo; directive.

Given all these details, I'd be tempted to conclude that MSVC is wrong. Even in this case, what might it be doing wrong (in implementation terms or in interpretation of the standard) to cause the error?

Looks like a bug in generated code?  I mean, if __builtin_array_init_helper properly scoped its types you wouldn't see that error.  Otoh, this is no guarantee your code is valid.  Just means MSVC definitely screwed up.

Something like https://godbolt.org/z/4Ezsd4zsP should be IFNDR, I am pretty sure, because otherwise it would require the standard library implementer to qualify all names used in the C standard library, which doesn't sound reasonable. Maybe that is supposed to be the intent of https://eel.is/c++draft/extern.types#1, but that doesn't actually consider unqualified lookup from the the global namespace scope.

I wonder if the correct question is actually more along the lines of "not incorrect". Certainly, it would not surprise me if making size_t a built-in type is a legitimate choice.

FYI: MSVC seems to define/declare size_t in global namespace even without any headers. For example, the program int main(){size_t i;} compiles with msvc. Also Which C++ compilers automatically define size_t without requiring a header include?

MSVC is correct, your program is ill-formed. 16.4.5.3.5 says both ::T and std::T that correspond to C standard library are reserved, and size_t is defined in C, so you can't redefine it in global namespace by opening namespace: timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/extern.types#1

@Gene They are not defining size_t in the global namespace scope, nor does using namespace foo; prevent qualified lookup of ::size_t to denote something else than std::size_t. But as I wrote in my previous comment, I suspect that unqualified lookup of T from the global namespace scope is intended to be covered by that rule as well and that it is defect for it to not do so.

Or actually, the code is already wrong because none of the headers for std::size_t are included. If only e.g. <cstddef> was included, then maybe size_t is not declared in the global namespace scope and using namespace foo; may cause lookup for ::size_t to result in a different type than lookup for std::size_t. However, if e.g. <stddef.h> is included as well, then this can't happen.

@user17732522 So the demo in my previous comment is also ill-formed, right?

@user12002570 I think that is pretty clearly ill-formed and just one of MSVC's weird behaviors that it is known for.

@user17732522 - I don't think the Standard prohibits implementation from defining the Standard library types without including corresponding headers. Since the user code is prohibited from redefining those names regardless of includes implicit definition of size_t by compiler wouldn't contradict anything in the Standard.

@user12002570 -- ill-formed code allows MSVC do anything, including compiling it. So far I didn't see anything MSVC did wrong.

@Gene Ill-formed means that the compiler has to issue a diagnostic, unless the standard also says that no diagnostic is required (IFNDR). I don't see anything in [library] that would permit the compiler to declare standard library entities without a standard library #include. Arguably the standard library names aren't even reserved if no standard library header is included, see https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue1236.

@Gene No, that is not what ill-formed means. A compiler must emit a diagnostic for an ill-formed program.

@user17732522 - implementation is allowed to have extensions, for example defining size_t w/o including the header, but user code doing the same is ill-formed, it does require diagnostics though (you can blame MSVC for not doing this), but it's allowed to compile and execute such programs 4.1.1/9 https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.compliance#general-9

This question would really need a bounty, I think..........
